# WSO2 identity server and spring security oauth InvalidRequestException: Possible CSRF detected

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth-2.0, wso2-identity-server

I'm developing a web application exposing a RESTful service using springboot, spring security as a POC to compare different identity provider products.

Here is the application code

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@EnableZuulProxy
public class GatewayApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GatewayApplication.class, args);
    }    

}
```

And this is my cofig yaml file

```
security:
    oauth2:
        client:
            accessTokenUri: https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token
            clientAuthenticationScheme: header
            clientId: myClientId
            clientSecret: myClientSecret
            scope: openid
            userAuthorizationUri: https://localhost:9443/oauth2/authorize
            preEstablishedRedirectUri: http://localhost:8081/login
            useCurrentUri: false
        resource:
            userInfoUri: https://localhost:9443/oauth2/userinfo?schema=openid
        sso:
          login-path: /login

server:
    port: 8081
```

I've configured the application as a client in the WSO2-IS to enable oauth2/openId Connect authentication.

The problem is that every time the application tries to obtain the access token I got this exception

```sh
org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Could not obtain access token
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientContextFilter.doFilter(OAuth2ClientContextFilter.java:60)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.TraceFilter.doFilter(TraceFilter.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.exceptions.InvalidRequestException: Possible CSRF detected - state parameter was required but no state could be found
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.getParametersForTokenRequest(AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.java:255)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.obtainAccessToken(AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.java:209)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.acquireAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:221)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.getAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:173)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:105)
    ... 63 common frames omitted
```

I have debugged the authentication flow several times and localized the failure point and the problematic request..

This is the failure point in `AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider`

```
Object preservedState = request.getPreservedState();
// Here preservedState is null but it should be a String with "http://localhost:8081/login"
        if (request.getStateKey() != null || stateMandatory) {

            if (preservedState == null) {
                throw new InvalidRequestException(
                        "Possible CSRF detected - state parameter was required but no state could be found");
            }
        }
```

And this is the request

```
Received [GET /login?code=d3ee114c-b4b3-32d5-9633-73b8e01431b8&state=tv7Pc3&session_state=3ff781cd9ac5487405d521ad65b70ffbe42f12135d220feab382d39cf478650e.H_oNKR72M8o50w-t-l8kUw HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8081
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1

]
```

I used this application to test Keycloak and I didn't have this issue. The same request using Keycloak looks like this.

```
Received [GET /login?state=5X67Q5&code=vwbYpX_n5SqVHDOI5KDOAmHNgbvwkRneT_i8k7t4v_o.9dc94ecc-aeb8-4f0c-8fa5-ab4d327ecdb0 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8081
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/pocauthapplication/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=zuul_proxy&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8081/login&response_type=code&state=5X67Q5
Cookie: JSESSIONID=0C5F8417267F3DDB8C84F107F6B831B9
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1

]
```

I think the problem is in the missing Referer header that makes the application thinks that the request could be a forged request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the reason why the referer header lost when oauth flow backs to my application from the IS.

The main reason is because the WSO2-IS uses https and my application uses plain http. So when the authentication flow chages it's context from https to http referer header is lost.

I proved to disable https on the WSO2-IS and it works.

Here is the request when it backs to my service with https disabled.

```
[GET /login?code=70041d7b-9f54-36f8-bf70-f663f73b5441&state=v1JocO&session_state=cf6fe250a8512d7a2100ab5cf1b62d68e070634aa3e5d704746a030a8674f398.p4OxMoMTuIWd-JiBa-x0pQ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8081
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://localhost:9443/authenticationendpoint/login.do?client_id=42zjjBHYEwvKTwwtFScNG6P1NJ4a&commonAuthCallerPath=%2Foauth2%2Fauthorize&forceAuth=false&passiveAuth=false&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8081%2Flogin&response_type=code&scope=openid&state=v1JocO&tenantDomain=carbon.super&sessionDataKey=1b1ce4f8-b1ad-48d0-9814-e8db0dd84732&relyingParty=42zjjBHYEwvKTwwtFScNG6P1NJ4a&type=oidc&sp=zuul_proxy&isSaaSApp=false&authenticators=BasicAuthenticator:LOCAL
Cookie: JSESSIONID=C028E69ED0DB92DA06BDFCFA852C4ACB
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1

]
```